# Starting network connection from Ubuntu recovery?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I tried to upgrade Ubuntu from Hardy to Intrepid last night, and seem to have killed it.

I can boot into "recovery mode" and the root shell, but it freezes when it tries to start the Gnome environment etc.

In this recovery mode it doesn't seem to be on the network (ie. ifconfig shows the lo bit but not the eth0 bit) And I can't ping or ssh to it.

How can I start networking from this prompt?

cheers

phil

Comment: I wrote http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/network-troubleshooting.html a network troubleshooting guide, a while ago and should help you find out what the problem is. It should take you from checking your network driver to making sure your IP configuration is correct.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Do you normally get your IP address from DHCP server ?

```
$ ifconfig eth0 up 
$ sudo dhclient eth0
```

To set IP address you want (for example 192.168.0.1) type:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add default gw GATEWAY-IP eth0
```

If you have a problem with gdm during the boot, switch to the real console:

Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut keys to switch to the first console.

To switch back to Desktop mode (`gdm`), use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> shortcut keys.

Comment: Don't forget to add your default gateway (if you want internet access): route add default gw <gateway-ip>

Comment: +1 Still works on 12.04. PS: you don't need `sudo` in recovery mode.

Comment: Formatting @MattSimmons ' comment for n00bs like me:   `route add default gw <gateway-ip>`

Comment: just adapter-name, to be specific to your environment. e.g. eth0, would be enp0s3 (default) in my case, when running on virtual machine. (+1)

Comment: can you be clear about more situations? Is this wifi, direct? What? No idea.

Answer (score 14):

## Step by step with `ip`

1. Get the name of the network interface with the `ip link` command. The name may differ with motherboards. It should be different from `lo`, the virtual local interface.

```
# ip link
```

2. Assuming the network interface is called `eth0`, the following command will bring the interface up. This should now be visible when executing the command `ip link` once more.

```
# ip link set eth0 up
# ip link
```

3. Next, a local IP address needs to be obtained from the router. The second command is again for checking.

```
# dhclient eth0
# ip addr show dev eth0
```

4. Finally, a temporary domain name server (DNS) is required to translate URLs to IP addresses. This can be either the router in the LAN (if previously/automatically properly configured), the DNS of the ISP or —if you still trust them— Google's DNS at `8.8.8.8` This requires editing a system configuration file that normally should not be edited. However, any changes made will automatically disappear when rebooting.

```
# nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Add a line containing, for example:

```
nameserver 192.168.178.1
```

### Some more helpful commands

Personally, I ended up in this dire situation by replacing an NVidia video card with a much older model. Once the networking established, the following set of commands allowed me to successfully install the proper NVidia card driver.

```
# update-drivers autoinstall
# update-initramfs -k all -u
# update-grub
```

Comment: This is much more useful than the accepted answer if you have newer version of Ubuntu that doesn't come with net-tools for ifconfig. +1

Answer (score 7):

To start networking, `/etc/init.d/networking start` should do the trick.  I'd say that if Gnome isn't starting, you've got X config problems.  If you disable gdm from starting on boot, then you should be able to get to a regular console prompt and do diagnosis from there (check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and so on).

Answer (score 7):

In newer versions of Ubuntu name resolution does not work via `/etc/resolv.conf` anymore. 
Thus you need to do something like

```
dhclient eno1
systemctl start systemd-resolved
```

Comment: this is what worked for me on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: worked for me, ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This fixed my networking issue from terminal on ubuntu 22.04 LTS  ..

Answer (score 3):

You can go back to the recovery menu options by login-out (cntrl + D), then select the option "Network ------- Enable networking" and Ubuntu will do the rest for you to activate networking. You will be brought back to this menu screen, so you can get back to the shell prompt and continue whatever you were trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just start the network manager in recovery mode

```
systemctl start network-manager
```