# Recover network connection from ubuntu 22.04 console after crash

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, crash

my perfectly operational ubuntu machine with nvidia GTX 1650 crashed when I tried `sudo apt-get remove python3`

Now it boots directly into terminal. When I run startx it shows a graphical window with message oh no something went wrong and logout button. clicking the button brings me back to terminal.

ping google.com results in temporary problem in name resolution and cant find the domain.

running ifconfig results in ifconfig not found. it doesn’t find eth0

a. Can you help me restore network connection ?
b. restart X

I already tried this SO post -

[Start network connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/21475/starting-network-connection-from-ubuntu-recovery#)

Update -

tried following commands with no promising results -

`ip link` shows output 1: lo … and 2. eno1 … but no eth0 . So its not detecting my network card / port. Any solution ?

Since my machine fully connected and working before with a wired connection, I am hoping, I can restore the connection without a full reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use eno1 and config it as your network interface ...

Network adapter naming can be changed buy Linux:
eth1 -> is the onboard Ethernet (wired) adapter on your Linux machine.
eno1 -> is your embedded NIC (onboard Network Interface Card). It is a regular physical network interface.